# If $A$ is not $\varepsilon$-dense in a unit disk $B$, then $B\setminus A$ contains a disk of radius $\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $B$ be a unit disk on the plane and $A\subset B$.

I need to prove the following statement:

> If $A$ is not $\varepsilon$-dense in $B$ then $B\setminus A$ contains a smaller disk of radius $\varepsilon$.

Comment: What is the definition of $\,\varepsilon$-dense?

Comment: Ah, I think that $A\subset B$ is $\epsilon$-dense if for any $b\in B$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $d(a, b)<\epsilon$. Note that $d$ is the metric on plane.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is not $\varepsilon$-dense in $B$ then there exists $b \in B$ so that for every $a \in A$ $d(a,b) \geq \varepsilon$. Then for such $b$ disk $\{ s \in B \mid d(s, b) < \varepsilon \} \subseteq B \setminus A$.

Comment: thank you P.K. in this case can we say that $\lbrace s\in B:d(s, b)<\epsilon\rbrace$ has positive measure?